# Is it possible to pass parameter to $http factory that returns dataReturn?

Tags: angularjs

here is a set up for me to call a php script to get data from an external API. What I did is to set up a factory like such:

```
app.factory('loadAPI', function ($http) {
  var doRequest = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'JSON',
      url: 'api.php'
    });
  };
  return {
    dataReturn: function() { return doRequest(); }
  };
});
```

And then inside my `.controller` I use the following script to process data:

```
loadAPI.dataReturn().success(function(data, status){

...

}
```

Now since the external API provides many interfaces, I like to pass parameter to the `.factory` so it can process multiple different type of interfaces (instead of creating multiple `.factory` to process them).

Here is my concept:

```
loadAPI.dataReturn(parameter).success(function(data, status){

...

}

app.factory('loadAPI', function ($http) {
  var doRequest = function(parameter) {
    return $http({
      method: 'JSON',
      url: 'api.php?p=' + parameter
    });
  };
  return {
    dataReturn: function(parameter) { return doRequest(parameter); }
  };
});
```

It didn't work.

Comment: *It didn't work.* and wich kind of error gives you? Be more specific

Comment: `JSON` isn't a valid `$http` method

Comment: Also, why so many nested functions? Simply `return { dataReturn: doRequest };`

Comment: Also, [something something deprecated *yawn*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Comment: @Phil, hey it is a commonly known method to nest the functions to use $http to get data, or it won't pass the data back. `return { dataReturn: doRequest }` or `return { dataReturn: doRequest() }` won't return data. I might not have stay on edge on the method, not sure about how to use `.then` it doesn't return data either.

Comment: @Luxor001 just no data return. No error message.

Comment: @Phil 'JSON' is actually, it is equal to 'GET' and it is easier to change to JSONP when needed.

Comment: No, it's not. There is `JSONP` however. `GET` is just the default which it will use if you don't specify a real method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept would work. I tried it and it returns data correctly. There perhaps are easier ways to pass the parameter to `$http`. I suspect something wrong with your `api.php` not reading the parameter correctly.